# XCTest change Queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, xctest

Is it possible to change the queue that is used in XCTest from the com.apple.main queue to a different one? I'm having troubles testing an App that also dispatches to this queue and thus does not enter a dispatch_async block. This phenomenon apparently has something to do with the used queue that is blocked by the tester. Is there a way to change the "dispatch_get_current_queue" output inside the XCTest tester?

Language: Objective C
XCode: 6.0.1
XCTest: Integrationtest with Hostapplication on an iPad
Target OS: iOS 7.1 and 8

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm running asynchronous Unit tests

Add this macros on top of unit tests.

```
// Macro - Set the flag for block completion
#define StartBlock() __block BOOL waitingForBlock = YES

// Macro - Set the flag to stop the loop
#define EndBlock() waitingForBlock = NO

// Macro - Wait and loop until flag is set
#define WaitUntilBlockCompletes() WaitWhile(waitingForBlock)

// Macro - Wait for condition to be NO/false in blocks and asynchronous calls
// Each test should have its own instance of a BOOL condition because of non-thread safe operations
#define WaitWhile(condition) \
do { \
while(condition) { \
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]]; \
} \
} while(0)
```

So the test can be written like this

```
- (void)testContentNode
{
    StartBlock();
    [AFContentNode loadContentWithUUID:@"d6d87899-94d4-4540-aeab-e88647e4ad61"
                            completion:^(AFMagnoliaNode *node, NSError *error)
     {
         XCTAssert(!error, @"Error raised: %@", error);
         XCTAssert(node, @"Node has not been fetched");
         EndBlock();
     }];
    WaitUntilBlockCompletes();
}
```

Comment: Does this work when testing with a testhost (integration test)? Or do you use a simulator?

Comment: I'm using simulator, but there should not be problem with testhost